# How to convert character to numeric in SAS when the variable has different length in each line?

Tags: mysql, sas

I read a few topics in here and other forums but I coudn't find this situation.
I have a table named Dataset with the customer id (a number with 5-11 digits). This is what customer id look like:

> 2768855898,00
>
> 22261256809,00
>
> 241240875,00
>
> 14440103871,00
>
> 33089003864,00
>
> 21674371888,00
>
> 2619599806,00
>
> 8546464855,00
>
> 5837486607,00

And I'm trying to take off the ',00' after the numbers. What I'm trying to do is to convert to numeric first and then convert to character. However, I've tried a few things and didn't work:

```
    DATA DATASET_NEW;
    SET DATASET;
    CUSTOMER_NEW=INPUT(CUSTOMER_NEW,10.);
    FORMAT CUSTOMER_NEW $10.;
    RUN;
```

A few lines of 'CUSTOMER_NEW' are blank.
I've also tried CUSTOMER_NEW=CUSTOMER*1 and CUSTOMER_NEW=CUSTOMER+0.
It didn't work. All lines are blank when doing this.
What should I do?

Comment: What's the type and format of the original variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the scan function to separate the components.

```
Customer_new = scan(customer, 1, ',');
```

Format customer_new $15.;